# Splitting array elements which contains some words and a number

Tags: bash, unix

I have an array with elements which contain a certain amount of words followed by digits.
EX: word1 word2

```
for i in "${array[@]}"
do

done

Example:
If array[0] = word1 word2 5
stringarray=word1 word2
valarray=5
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking for. Do you want all of the array's elements that have letters to be in one list, and the numbers to be in another?

Comment: agree, confusing. Show your use-case with required output. Good luck.

Comment: Yes that is correct @jirassimok. I will update the question

Comment: Maybe `case "$i" in *[A-Za-z]* ) stringArray+=("$i") ;; [0-9]|[0-9][0-9] ) numArr+=($i) ;; esac` every so slightly reduces the processing costs. Test to be sure. You can make the `numArr` as "wide" as you expect your numbers to be, i.e. `[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|...` Good luck.

Comment: `[....]` is a list in bash. POSIX defines certain *character classes* like `[:space:]` and `[:digit:]` (which you can use instead of `[0-9]`). See `man bash` under the heading *Pattern Matching*.

Answer (score 0):

In Bash, you can do regular expression comparison using the extended test command `[[` with the regular expression comparison operator `=~`.

I can't say this is the best way to do this, but it is probably the simplest:

```
array=("word1" "word2" "5" "some words" "123" "00" "the last words")
wordarray=()
numarray=()

for x in "${array[@]}"
do
   # if x contains any non-digit character
   if [[ $x =~ [^0-9] ]]
   then wordarray+=("$x")
   else numarray+=("$x")
   fi
done

for x in "${wordarray[@]}"
do echo "$x"
done

for x in "${numarray[@]}"
do echo "$x"
done

# Outputs:
# word1 / word2 / some words / the last words
# 5 / 123 / 00
```

This is a very simple detection strategy, and it won't catch decimals or negative numbers, but the regular expression can be modified to catch those relatively easily (there are many questions about that on this website).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your requirement correctry, please try the following:

```
# example of array[]
array=("word1 word2 5" "word3 6 word4")

for i in "${array[@]}"; do
    for j in $i; do
        if [[ -z ${j//[0-9]} ]]; then       # $j consists of numbers only
            numberarray+=("$j")
        else
            stringarray+=("$j")
        fi
    done
done

# see the results
echo "stringarray: ${stringarray[@]}"
echo "numberarray: ${numberarray[@]}"
```

Output:

```
stringarray: word1 word2 word3 word4
numberarray: 5 6
```